# Join between two one-to-many tables

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have these two table and I have to write this SQL query (Microsoft Access):

- Write a query showing for every author that sold any books how many titles (book_id) and how many units (quantity ordered) they sold

[image]

I have tried with this query but it doesn't work

```
SELECT authors.author_id, Count(orders.book_id) AS CountOfbook_id,
Sum(orders.quantity_ordered) AS SumOfquantity_ordered
FROM authors 
LEFT JOIN orders ON authors.book_id = orders.book_id
GROUP BY authors.author_id;
```

but it doesn't work because it counts many times the same book took from customersOrders[image]

Comment: So what did you try? What result did it produce/how is it different from what you wanted?

Comment: Please read http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557 and the accepted answer

Comment: I written the query I tried at the bottom

Comment: SQL, Microsoft Access

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this?

```
select author,sum(CountOfbook_id), sum(SumOfquantity_ordered)
from (
    SELECT authors.author_id as author, Count(orders.book_id) AS CountOfbook_id,
    Sum(orders.quantity_ordered) AS SumOfquantity_ordered
    FROM authors 
    LEFT JOIN orders ON authors.book_id = orders.book_id
    GROUP BY authors.author_id,authors.book_id;)
group by author;
```

Comment: I tried, but I got the same author twice, see: https://d2ppvlu71ri8gs.cloudfront.net/items/3W2B1G2t232C1p0i3J3f/Image%202017-06-02%20at%2011.51.59%20AM.png?v=59ceaca9

Comment: I have modified it